# Handlebars parsing object from method with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have the following situation:

```
{{#each .}}
    <tr class="gradeA">
      <td>{{Code}}</td>
      <td>{{getStudent.name}}</td>
    </tr> 
{{/each}}
```

getStudent is a method that takes a parameter (studentId) and returns an object of type student, I need to display many fields from this object using handlebars. For example, getStudent.name, getStudent.gpa, etc...

How can I do this using handlebars registerHelper?

This is the getStudent method:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getStudent", function getStudent(studentId) {
                    var student = {};
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "getstudent",
                        type : "get",
                        data : {
                            studentId : studentId
                        },
                        success : function(response) {
                            student = response;
                        },
                        async : false
                    });
                    return student;
                });
```

Comment: In my opinion it's a very bad idea to do it this way. You are effectively having your template making an AJAX call. Why not move this call to a view or controller and render your template when your AJAX call is finished?

Comment: @garethdn If I did it like this, how can I call it from inside handlebars {{each}} loop?

Comment: I don't know if you've got a collection of students or not but assuming you can fetch a collection of students then....`{{#each students}}Name: {{name}}, GPA: {{gpa}}{{/each}}`. It's hard to say without seeing a typical representation of the data you're trying to render.

Comment: @AliIssa you pass in the things you want to literate through as an array in your context. e.g. var context = { something: [{value: 1},{value: 2}, {value:3}] };  and in your template: {{#each something}} Value is {{value}} {{/each}}

Comment: the {{each .}} is not a list of students, it is a list of another object and inside it I need to get the student object, it is like a loop for x object and inside it I need to get a record from y object, all this in handlebars template